# Can I keep a reference to hazelcast replicatedmap or should I look it up every time

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am writing a hazelcast client in spring boot and I need to access a replicated map.
Can I look this up in my singleton bean constructor, or should I call `hz.getReplicatedMap("mymap")` every time I need it?

The client should of course restarts of the hazelcast members/servers.
I am using hazelcast 4.2.1 in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can look it up in your singleton bean constructor and keep using the reference.